# how to give commands to the cmd through a windows 8 app in c# for wifi hotspot

Tags: c#, windows-8, cmd

We are planning to develop a wifi hotspot app in windows appstore using XAML and C# in visual studio. We were unable to find any class or methods to access the command prompt from the desktop. We need to type the below code to start a hotspot connection using internet sharing in windows 8:
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow 
ssid=ConnectionName key=8Characters
We need to have a solution to this problem somehow through which we can send the above commands to the command prompt and start a connection using windows 8 app. 
Please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions asked on SO should show evidence of prior research and reasonable effort towards finding a solution. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=_pYsU4iuNILWyQGA2oCgBQ&usg=AFQjCNEPXd2IAG2utSYKtDsFXdi1sdIkHg&sig2=-6VWPk2_pAQOIZmMJrvYtg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.aWc) to execute commands.

Sample code, copied almost verbatim from the documentation, modified for your needs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "%Windir%\System32\netsh.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ConnectionName key=8Characters ";
                myProcess.Start();
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself.  
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it  
                // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically 
                // from this application using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a batch file and have your program run that file on startup.

something.bat with

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ConnectionName key=8Characters
```